# PHP SOAP Call Format

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need to make an SOAP call to another system. I used [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) called it with my `wsdl` file and got this `$soap->__getLastRequest()`:

```
<ns1:getData>
  <sqlName xsi:type="xsd:string">getDataBESTAND</sqlName>
  <sqlParameter xsi:type="xsd:string">MANDANT=029</sqlParameter>
  <ziel xsi:type="xsd:string">PISTEST</ziel>
</ns1:getData>
```

But the target system can't read it. I was told it should like more like this:

```
<vas:getData xmlns:vas="vasws.Query"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <sqlName xsi:type="xsd:string">getDataBESTAND</sqlName>
  <sqlParameter xsi:type="xsd:string">MANDANT=029</sqlParameter>
  <ziel xsi:type="xsd:string">PISTEST</ziel>
</vas:getData>
```

Can I configure the PHP SOAP Client to this format or how would I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the customer gave me the wrong URL for the request. Both query do work.

For the first `ns1` must be defined in the `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns1="vasws.Query" ...`